# How to keep same css counter value for two elements

Tags: html, css, css-counter

I have a requirement to show same CSS counter value for two elements based on some attribute value or class.
For Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  counter-reset: section;
}
h2::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "Section " counter(section) ": ";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>CSS Counter</h1>
<h2>Point A</h2>
<h2>Point B</h2>
<h2 class="a">Point C</h2>
<h2>Point D</h2>
<h2>Point E</h2>
<h2 class="a">Point C</h2>
<h2>Point F</h2>
</html>
```

This is the current output

[image]

Is it possible that the h2 elements having the same class a, have the same count in front of them, i.e both Point C have section 3 in front of them.
This is the desired output

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this using css and html?

Answer (score 0):

manually you can change counter by resetting particular class:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section;
}

h2::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "Section " counter(section) ": ";
}

.a{ 
  color:red;
}

h2.mcount::before {
  counter-reset: section 2; 
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS Counter</h1>
<h2>Point A</h2>
<h2>Point B</h2>
<h2 class="a a">Point C</h2>
<h2>Point D</h2>
<h2>Point E</h2>
<h2 class="a mcount">Point C</h2>
<h2>Point F</h2>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it dynamically?

Comment: I hope you got the answer to your question that "Is it possible to achieve this using CSS and HTML?" I have not yet tried how it can be used dynamically, but I think it might be possible if you are able to create dynamic CSS and add style to HTML and class to h2.